# Class report with first pages numbered with roman numbers instead arabic numbers

Tags: page-numbering

I have written a report that contains in the first pages a thank you and a gift I want to number them in Roman numerals and delete the Arabic numerals

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[left=3cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LAE,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[arabic,french]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{arabtex} 
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}
{Definition}[section]
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsthm,amsmath,amssymb,mathrsfs,eso-pic}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\mathchardef\times="202
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Table des figures}
\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Liste des tableaux}
\chapter*{Abréviation}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abréviation}
\chapter*{\centering Remerciements}


\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\chapter*{\begin{center} Introduction générale
\end{center}} 
\pagestyle{empty}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\rhead{\emph{ Généralités sur les Radars à Synthése d'Ouverture}}
\lhead{\emph{Chapitre 1}}
\chapter{chap1} 
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Polarimétrie}
\subsection{Introduction à la polarisation}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can simply use `\pagenumbering{Roman}` for upper roman numbers or `\pagenumbering{roman}` or use commands `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter.`

See the following mwe

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{blindtext} % dummy text


\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman} % <===============================================
\tableofcontents
\pagestyle{empty}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Table des figures}
\pagestyle{empty}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Liste des tableaux}
\pagestyle{empty}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\chapter*{Abréviation}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abréviation}
\pagestyle{empty}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\chapter*{\centering Remerciements}

\pagestyle{empty}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic} % <==============================================
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

and the resulting TOC

[image: TOC]

## UPDATE:

It seems that at last your used `\usepackage[arabic,french]{babel}` is the culprit here. See the following changed mwe based your given code after your edit. I commented several packages and moved `hyperref` to be called last.

With the following mwe

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[left=3cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[LAE,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[arabic,french]{babel} % <==================================
\usepackage[french]{babel} % <==========================================

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]

\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}

%\usepackage{arabtex} 

\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt} % <=======================================

\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{hyperref} % <===============================================

\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\mathchardef\times="202



\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{Roman} % <===============================================
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Table des figures}
\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Liste des tableaux}
\chapter*{Abréviation}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abréviation}
\chapter*{\centering Remerciements}

\clearpage % <==========================================================
\pagenumbering{arabic} % <==============================================
%\setcounter{page}{1} % usually done by pagenumbering
\chapter*{\begin{center} Introduction générale
\end{center}} 
\pagestyle{empty}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\rhead{\emph{ Généralités sur les Radars à Synthése d'Ouverture}}
\lhead{\emph{Chapitre 1}}
\chapter{chap1} 
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Polarimétrie}
\subsection{Introduction à la polarisation}
\blindtext
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

you get the result:

[image: resulting toc]

Now uncoment the line with `babel` and option `arabic` (and of course comment the other call of `babel`) and you get a lot of warnings and missing roman numbers.

As already said, I do not know arabic language and its problems typesetting in LaTeX. Can you ask this special problems in an local arabic user group?

Comment: The numbers do not work in Arabic

Comment: Thanks Thanks Thanks Thanks Thanks Thanks Thanks Thanks Thanks